# three20 PhotoVC: changing index of photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

how do I set the T20 PhotoViewer to switch it's current photo to one from its photoSource array at a certain index?

The same way scrolling increments an index and shows a new photo, I want to set a photo index on an init method.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a `TTPhoto` to the `TTPhotoViewController`'s `centerPhoto` property, where the new `TTPhoto` you assign is one of the photos in the `TTPhotoSource`.  The `TTPhotoViewController` will look at the new photo's `index`, and use it.